# Save csv testing data in google colab?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have already make a prediction of testing data, but now I want to save the output of the testing data csv format to google drive. Can anyone help me?

```
test_preds = predict_dl(test_dl, model_resnet18)

test_preds = [p.item() for p in test_preds]
test_preds
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
test_preds = pd.DataFrame(test_preds).to_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/test_preds.csv')
```